# did const int& pass a reference or a copy

Tags: c++, function, reference, constants

For example,

```
void func(const int& a);
int main()
{
    int b=1;
    func(b*2);
}
```

If the `const int&` will pass a reference, how can `b*2` be a reference?

So it means it only pass a copy of `b*2` to `func()`?

But if so, did `func(b)` really pass a reference of `b`?

Am I right?

Comment: References to constants can be bound to temporary values (a.k.a. [rvalues](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#rvalue)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple:

```
int b = 1;
```

Here, `b` is an **lvalue**. so when you write `func( b )` then you are passing an **lvalue** to the `func`. And it works since `func` can take an **lvalue** by reference.

But:

```
func( b*2 );
```

Here, `b*2` is a **prvalue** (which is under the **rvalue** category) and when you write `func( b*2 );` then you are passing an **rvalue** to the `func`. And it works since `void func(const int& a);` has a *const lvalue reference* parameter and *const lvalue references* can bind to rvalues.

Now if you rewrite your function like this `void func(const int&& a);` so that it only takes **rvalues** as its argument (notice the `&&`), then `func( b*2 )` will still compile but `func( b )` won't because `b` is an **lvalue** and **lvalues** can not be moved unless you cast it to an **xvalue** (which is also under the **rvalue** and **glvalue** category) like this:

```
func( std::move( b ) )
```

In short, `std::move` casts an **lvalue** to an **xvalue** to tell the compiler that it is temporary and thus can be moved from.

*For the sake of completeness:*

> In C++11, expressions that:

> - have identity and cannot be moved from are called lvalue expressions;
> - have identity and can be moved from are called xvalue expressions;
> - do not have identity and can be moved from are called prvalue ("pure rvalue") expressions;
> - do not have identity and cannot be moved from are not used.

> The expressions that have identity are called "glvalue expressions" (glvalue stands for "generalized lvalue"). Both lvalues and xvalues are glvalue expressions.

> The expressions that can be moved from are called "rvalue expressions". Both prvalues and xvalues are rvalue expressions.

[image: It's as simple as this!]

Check [value category](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) for more info.

Comment: @Altman Jeffry Check the image for a better understanding.

Answer (score 5):

The `&` in this example indeed does denote a reference, so it has to refer to an actual object.

`b*2` creates a *temporary* `int` object in memory (an rvalue). When the statement `func(b*2);` is finished (ie, when the `;` is reached), that temporary will be destroyed.

While the statement `func(b*2)` is still running, the temporary still exists. A reference-to-const can bind to a temporary/rvalue object, which is why the code compiles and runs fine.

However, a non-const reference cannot bind to a temporary/rvalue, only to a named variable (an lvalue). So, if you were to drop the `const` (ie `void func(int& a)`) then the statement `func(b*2)` would no longer compile.